# Debian squeeze kernel update under Security Updates

Tags: linux, debian, linux-kernel

Can someone explain what squeeze1 and squeeze3 designate at the end of a kernel name?
For instance 2.6.32-48squeeze3 is showing up under Security Updates in Aptitude.

Answer (score 2):

Those suffix is because it's a specific version for stable/oldstable Debian Version. And those versions  only have security updates. For example, 2.6.32-48squeeze3 version. You can find more information [here](http://www.debian.org/security/2013/dsa-2668).